# The syntax of the command is incorrect. Makefile:2: recipe for target '...' failed

Tags: makefile, cmd

I'm trying to use a makefile to download a zip file to my project. But everytime I try to run `make build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip`it gives me the following output:

> mkdir -p build/
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> makefile:2: recipe for target 'build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip' failed
>
> make: *** [build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip] Error 1

Here is my makefile code:

```
build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    curl -o $@ http\://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/$(notdir $@)
```

Comment: I've put a "\" in front of "/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip" and it made the error go away, but now I'm still stuck with a "No rule to make target 'gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip'. Stop." Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code was run the slash in between "Build" and "gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip" made the command prompt think it was the end of that line and tried to run "mkdir -p build/". I've put a backslash in front of it so it would be handled as a piece of the path. My code still gives me an error but this question and this specific error is solved.

Comment: Could you explain a bit and add code of where you put the backslash? I am having the exact same problem!